# How can I undistort an image in Matlab using the known camera parameters?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

This is easy to do in [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) however I would like a native Matlab implementation that is fairly efficient and can be easily changed. The method should be able to take the camera parameters as specified in the above link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now do that as of release R2013B, using the Computer Vision System Toolbox.  There is a GUI app called [Camera Calibrator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/single-camera-calibrator-app.html) and a function [undistortImage](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/undistortimage.html).

Answer (score 13):

The simplest and most common way of doing undistort (also called unwarp or compensating for lens distortion) is to do a forward distortion on a chosen output photo size and then a reverse mapping using bilinear interpolation.

Here is code I wrote for performing this:

```
function I = undistort(Idistorted, params)
fx = params.fx;
fy = params.fy;
cx = params.cx;
cy = params.cy;
k1 = params.k1;
k2 = params.k2;
k3 = params.k3;
p1 = params.p1;
p2 = params.p2;

K = [fx 0 cx; 0 fy cy; 0 0 1];

I = zeros(size(Idistorted));
[i j] = find(~isnan(I));

% Xp = the xyz vals of points on the z plane
Xp = inv(K)*[j i ones(length(i),1)]';

% Now we calculate how those points distort i.e forward map them through the distortion
r2 = Xp(1,:).^2+Xp(2,:).^2;
x = Xp(1,:);
y = Xp(2,:);

x = x.*(1+k1*r2 + k2*r2.^2) + 2*p1.*x.*y + p2*(r2 + 2*x.^2);
y = y.*(1+k1*r2 + k2*r2.^2) + 2*p2.*x.*y + p1*(r2 + 2*y.^2);

% u and v are now the distorted cooridnates
u = reshape(fx*x + cx,size(I));
v = reshape(fy*y + cy,size(I));

% Now we perform a backward mapping in order to undistort the warped image coordinates
I = interp2(Idistorted, u, v);
```

To use it one needs to know the camera parameters of the camera being used.
I am currently using the PMD CamboardNano which according to the Cayim.com forums has the parameters used here:

```
params = struct('fx',104.119, 'fy', 103.588, 'cx', 81.9494, 'cy', 59.4392, 'k1', -0.222609, 'k2', 0.063022, 'k3', 0, 'p1', 0.002865, 'p2', -0.001446);

I = undistort(Idistorted, params);

subplot(121); imagesc(Idistorted);
subplot(122); imagesc(I);
```

Here is an example of the output from the Camboard Nano. Note: I artificially added border lines to see what the effect was of the distortion close to the edges (its much more pronounced):
[image]

Comment: What kind of data types does your function support? I can't make it work with any I tried... BTW: thanks for the function, its weird how matlab does not have this implemented

Comment: @AnderBiguri it should at least work with single channel type "double". First thing to do is convert any image to double. Also if you have an image which is grayscale or its a depth image then it should work fine just calling undistort with the correct params. If you have a 3 channel color image you will need to undistort separately on each channel.

Comment: It doesnt work with grayscale bitmaps, but I'll convert them to double and try!