# Error in removing the fisheye lens distortion of an image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fisheye

I have the following image:

[image]

I want to remove the fisheye lens distortion from this image, so I used the following code:

```
[X,map] = imread('Foam_Image.jpg');  % Read the indexed image
options = [size(X,1) size(X,2) 1];   % An array containing the columns, rows and exponent
tf = maketform('custom',2,2,[],...   % Make the transformation structure
               @fisheye_inverse,options);
newImage = imtransform(X,tf); 
imshow(newImage);                    % show image
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error using imtransform>parse_inputs (line 438)
XData and YData could not be automatically determined.  Try specifying XData and YData explicitly in the call to
IMTRANSFORM.

Error in imtransform (line 265)
args = parse_inputs(varargin{:});
```

I also used `imwarp` instead of `imtransform`, but I still get an error. Anyone has any idea why do I get this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, you need to manually specify the `XData` and `YData` properties during the call to `imtransform` with the Name-Property arguments syntax.

According to the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtransform.html?refresh=true), XData for example is:

> A two-element, real vector that, when combined with 'YData', specifies
>   the spatial location of the output image B in the 2-D output space
>   X-Y. The two elements of 'XData' give the x-coordinates (horizontal)
>   of the first and last columns of B, respectively.

and likewise for `YData`. Therefore, you could modify your call to `imtransform` like so:

```
newImage = imtransform(X,tf,'XData',[1 col],'YData',[1 row]);
```

where `col` and `row` are the output of the size function you calculated earlier.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have an error. I did like this:             `x = size(X,1);
y = size(X,2);                                                                                                         newImage = imtransform(X,tf,'XData',[1 x],'YData',[1 y]);`

Comment: `XData` represents the number of columns, so here it would be `[ 1 size(X,2) ] ` Maybe that's not the cause of the error though.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I meant `x=size(X,2)`, so the error is still there. I think I am using the wrong function though, `@fisheye_inverse`, because I want to remove the fisheye distortion from an already distorted image, not to implement it.. this function actually implements the distortion, I think.

Comment: mhh yes actually I think you're right. Have you taken the function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589851/how-can-i-implement-a-fisheye-lens-effect-barrel-transformation-in-matlab)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Unfortunately, I don't know of any function that inverses the distortion.

Comment: Me neither sorry. If you have the Computer Vision Toolbox you might want to check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117825/how-can-i-undistort-an-image-in-matlab-using-the-known-camera-parameters)

Comment: Thank you, I am checking out.