# MATLAB - error using imtransform()

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I got an error when trying to run the imtransform() line in my code. I got:

```
Error using imtransform>parse_inputs (line 438)
XData and YData could not be automatically determined.
Try specifying XData and YData explicitly in the call to
IMTRANSFORM.

Error in imtransform (line 265)
args = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Error in main (line 9)
newImage = imtransform(rgbImage,tf);  %# Transform the image
```

I used the function tf = maketform() to generate the transformation itself.
So, in order to figure out what wrong with my code  i simplified as much as I can the function:

```
function U = fisheye_inverse(X)
   U = X;
end
```

and my code looked like this:

```
rgbImage = imread('IMG-20150622-WA0046.jpg');  %# Read the image
tf = maketform('custom',2,2,[],...    %# Make the transformation structure
           @fisheye_inverse,options);
newImage = imtransform(rgbImage,tf);  %# Transform the image
imshow(newImage);
```

and still the code yell at me this error again.
I looked at a similar problem [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115164/error-in-removing-the-fisheye-lens-distortion-of-an-image-in-matlab%22HERE%22) that posted here in the past, but no one answer the question in the end.

Thanks in advance, Gal :)

Comment: Why doesn't the answer on the other link explain it to you? Seems clear to me. You need to specify `XData` and `YData`, because the code can't work it out automatically (probably because you are using a custom transform).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in removing the fisheye lens distortion of an image in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115164/error-in-removing-the-fisheye-lens-distortion-of-an-image-in-matlab)

Comment: first, thanks for your comments. Second, i didn't mention it in my later message (my bad, sorry), but when i specify the Xdata and Ydata i get also an error message:
_Error using moveRight_
_Too many input arguments_
so i still don't know how to solve this.

my code look like this:

Comment: _newImage = imtransform(rgbImage,tf,'XData',[1 size(rgbImage,1)], 'YData',[1 size(rgbImage,2)])_
(Sorry for the second comment but the edit button dont let me edit)

Comment: Use `dbstop if error` and figure out where and how `moveRight` is being called.  Also, you might not be able to edit your comment but you should be able to edit your question at any time.